# How to emulate window title bar in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        table {border: 1px solid black; width: 500px}
        .title {height: 40px}
        .close {float: right}
        td {text-align: center; border: 1px solid black} 
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">  Centered  <span class="close">XXXXX</span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, the "XXXX" is indeed placed to the right, but this causes the "Centered" text to be offset slightly to the left. This is because the "XXXX" is still taking up space in the document flow next to the text "Centered". How can I have it so "Centered" is centered exactly like the rest of the table?

heres and example rendering:

[rendering http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9659/screenshoteoo.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9659/screenshoteoo.png)

Comment: Will this be a fixed width table, with fixed width 'XXXX' value?

Comment: @PortageMonkey in my case, yes. But the best solution would be one where it can be variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely position the span.close, it won't take up space and your title should be perfectly centered:

```
tr td {
  position: relative;
}

tr td span.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**Edit** Whoops - never encountered that before.  Normally a parent with position: relative will act as the coordinate system for a child with position: absolute, but not in the case of a <td>.   If you wrap your title and span.close in a <div> with the following code you should be in business:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4 strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {border: 1px solid black; width: 500px}  

        .title div {
           position: relative; 
           height: 40px; 
         }            

        td {text-align: center; border: 1px solid black}             

        td span.close {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">  
              <div>Centered  <span class="close">XXXXX</span></div>  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This won't work unless the TD is absolutly positioned. Otherwise the "top:0 right:0" is ancored to the entire document: http://img196.imageshack.us/i/screenshot1kkn.png/